# Some issues with js/jQuery in wordpress on xampp

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, xampp, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap in order to end some site. I need to prepare it for wordpress. I did it in 60%, but i can't do one thing. My jquery/js functions doesn't work. Things like: popup, smooth scrolling and more. Can someone help me?

```js
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

function b2w_theme_styles(){

    wp_enqueue_style('boostrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('xtyle_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('simple_line_icons',get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/simple-line-icons/css/simple-line-icons.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('popup_css',get_template_directory_uri() . '/vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_styles');

function b2w_theme_js(){
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'bootstrap.js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/wp-content/themes/Atut/js/creative.min.js', array('jquery'), null,true);
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'bootstrap_bundle.js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/wp-content/themes/Atut/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'), null,true);
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'jquery_min.js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.2.1',true);
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'bootstrap_bundle_min.js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js', array('jquery'),null,true);
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'scrollreveal_min.js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/vendor/scrollreveal/scrollreveal.min.js', array('jquery'),'3.2.1',true);
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'jquery_magnific-popup_min.js',get_template_directory_uri(). '/vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js', array('jquery'),null,true);
    wp_enqueuue_script( 'easing_js',get_template_directory_uri() .'/vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js', array('jquery'), null,true);

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_styles');

function shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery() {

 wp_deregister_script('jquery');
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'shapeSpace_include_custom_jquery');
```

Comment: What Parsa answered... If you use the browser developer tools, you'd see the files are not loading which would lead you to review closely your `add_action`s. See [What are browser developer tools? - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a duplicate `add_action`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_styles');
```

Change one of those `add_action` to:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'b2w_theme_js');
```